# PHP/MySQL display/order additional information on various pages

Tags: php, mysql

In my page i have a block of content where i want to display certain additional information on the side of it. This information can be the same for several pages, but items can also be displayed on one specific item.

I'm thinking about different approached, but all my solutions seem, in my opinion, too exhaustive or i can't imagine that there isn't a more clever solution.

Consider the following table (column-names differ from my original database, i don't use the same name in different tables) i have for the content.

```
fe_content:
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+
| id |  page  | pagelink |      content      |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+
| 1  | page 1 |  page_1  | Content of page 1 |
| 2  | page 2 |  page_2  | Content of page 2 |
| 3  | page 3 |  page_3  | Content of page 3 |
| 4  | page 4 |  page_4  | Content of page 4 |
| 5  | page 5 |  page_5  | Content of page 5 |
+----+--------+----------+-------------------+
```

My approach for the additional data is something like:

```
fe_blocks:
+----+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| id |  block  | order | display | pagelink |      content       |
+----+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| 1  | block 1 |   1   | always  |          | Content of block 1 |
| 2  | block 2 |   2   | always  |          | Content of block 2 |
| 3  | block 3 |   1   | single  |  page_1  | Content of block 3 |
| 4  | block 4 |   3   | always  |          | Content of block 4 |
| 5  | block 5 |   4   | single  |  page_3  | Content of block 5 |
+----+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

So now, when i want to display the page, i use:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT content
    FROM fe_content
    WHERE pagelink = '"._mysql_real_escape_string($_aGET[0])."'
") or die(mysql_error());
$show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo("<div> ".$show['content']." </div>\n\n<aside>\n");
```

$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT content
    FROM fe_blocks
    WHERE pagelink = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_aGET[0])."' or display = 'always'
    ORDER BY order ASC
") or die(mysql_error());
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo("<p>".$show['content']."</p>\n");
}
echo("</aside>");

This gives me the desired blocks, but with some snags..

Suppose i request `page_1`, my output will be

```
<div> Content of page 1 </div>
<aside>
<p>Content of block 1</p>
<p>Content of block 2</p>
<p>Content of block 3</p>
<p>Content of block 4</p>
</aside>
```

While i want to get this instead:

```
<div> Content of page 1 </div>
<aside>
<p>Content of block 3</p>
<p>Content of block 1</p>
<p>Content of block 2</p>
<p>Content of block 4</p>
</aside>
```

my desired results take into account:

- *Importance.* The order of items that are displayed on a specific page should be considered more important (e.g. overrule) than the order of items that are always displayed.
- *Almost always.* Perhaps some items should be displayed on almost all pages, except a few. With respect to future changes it is not convenient to insert a new row in the database  with the appropriate pagelink with it for each page where the block should be displayed.

Anybody some thoughts on this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pages and you have blocks. If you want one block to be displayed on multiple pages, you should make a new table that would help you store n:m connections between entities. Thats where you will store order in which certain block will be on certain page. Basically - normalize your data.

Comment: That's probably the best tip! Thanks!

Comment: That solution is cleaner in design, but you have to mantain for each page the order of related data; then you are just moving the sorting problem, because for each page you have to sort items with same logic you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by like this:

```
ORDER BY order ASC, display ASC
```

so with same order number, "always" comes before

or if you want to give more importance to "display"

```
ORDER BY display ASC, order ASC
```

Comment: Makes sense, weird i didn't come up with that in this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alter your Second query statement like this,

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT content
FROM fe_blocks
WHERE pagelink = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_aGET[0])."' or display = 'always'
ORDER BY order ASC, display ASC ") or die(mysql_error());
```